# How do return value from lambda function via jdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, java-8

```
public List<User> getAll(){

        jdbcTemplate.query(query, rs -> {
            Map<Integer, User> userMap= new HashMap<>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                // adding elements

            }
            System.out.println(userMap.values()); // shows me correct result
            return userMap.values(); // not returning
        });
        return null;
    }
```

This method returning me null and ignoring return inside lambda function.
How I can receive data which I got inside the lambda?

Comment: return `jdbcTemplate.query(...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jdbcTemplate.query` will return whatever you returned on the lambda function, in this case. Look at the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-).

So you could do:

```
public List<User> getAll(){
    return jdbcTemplate.query(query, rs -> {
        Map<Integer, User> userMap= new HashMap<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            // adding elements
        }
        return userMap.values();
    });
}
```